# MKMapView World Region

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I have a MKMapview with 320 points Width and 120 points Height

I use this code to show whole world on mapview,

```
[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate zoomLevel:0 animated:NO];
```

But MKMapView SDK acts different in iOS 5 and iOS 6.1

Top map is at iOS 5
Bottom is at iOS 6.1

I always want to show like top image. How can i fix it in iOS 6 and above?

Thanks.

[image: Top:iOS5 Bottom:iOS6]

Comment: I tried `[mapView setVisibleMapRect:MKMapRectWorld animated:NO]` with similar results, so I guess the minimum zoom each SDK is different, although neither actually shows the whole world.

Comment: I can understand not showing whole world because of the mapview's frame but there must be a way to center user location with zoom 0.

Answer (score 0):

Apple now uses vector map in ios6, earlier it was using bitmap map. Also it has started using its own tiles and not of google map tiles
You can not control this behaviour so what you can do is try using Google Maps for iOS.

Integrating google maps for both ios5 & ios6 will give same result...

[Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/intro)

Comment: Thanks, maybe i'll try Google Maps.